# How to setup SSH tunnel proxy server?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, forwarding

I've encountered multiple applications that don't support SSH tunneling, and that has become an issue when working off-site from our servers.

I have a Raspberry Pi sitting here which is never turned off, and was wondering if it is possible to route certain ports like 9200 (Elasticsearch) and 3306 (mysql) through an SSH tunnel to the remote servers?

I was able to achieve a connection with this command on the Raspberry Pi:

```
ssh -A -t -N -L 9200:localhost:9200 user@remoteserver
```

But it refuses to forward packets sent from my computer. It only works if I send packets as `localhost` on the Raspberry Pi.

Is there any way to forward the packets, and making this an ssh tunnel proxy server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*-g Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports*

Add `-g` and then connect from your computer to the Raspberry Pi.

**OR**

Use ssh as SOCKS proxy with the `-D` switch.
Eg. `ssh -t -N -D 9000 user@remoteserver`

Now you have a socks proxy on port 9000.

Run programs with a socks wrapper such as `tsocks`. Every TCP connection will go through the socks proxy and terminate on the remote server.

For HTTP, on a Raspberry Pi install an http proxy such as Polipo.

An example Polipo config:

```
proxyPort = 8118
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9000"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

Configure your web broswer to use the Raspberry Pi as a proxy server, http://rpi:8118